# Listing something recommended for publication on publication section

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, arxiv

This is my first post, so please let me know if I made any mistakes.

I am applying to math phd programs this year, and one of the things I encountered is that for multiple schools, they ask me to list publications if I have any. I have a paper currently recommended for publication by a peer-reviewed journal(it's on arxiv and thus accessible to public), but it's not strictly speaking accepted. Since usually I get an entire text box to fill in my answer, what I did was that I list my paper, the arxiv link, as well as it's status that it's recommended for publication in that textbox. The status I listed in answer to the question should make it clear that this is not yet published or accepted in this peer-reviewed journal, only that it's "highly probable", and that it's available on arxiv.

I was wondering if my approach here is ok. I am an honest student, but I also really want to emphasize that I have this paper which has been recommended somewhere along with the application other than just on my CV. One of my recommenders have also suggested that this should work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “recommended for publication”? Usual you would only get to see the referee reports together with the editor decision.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is that I've gotten referee reports back which suggested that they recommend my paper for publication after I fix a minor issue and resend the paper back to them, which I've done. Since the process takes usually months at least, I haven't heard back since then.

Comment: What I have done (in a different field) is use such phrases as "In revision (minor revision)" or "Accepted pending minor revisions" depending on which fits the Reviewers' and Editor's feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me suggest that you be conservative in such things as some might judge you as padding your record which would be to your disadvantage.

If a form is flexible enough you could list it as long as you add the note that it is submitted and likely to be published based on the recommendations of reviewers. It certainly is not yet a publication and won't be until acceptance, at which time is is still "to appear".

But it is also sufficient, I think, to just list it in the CV as Work In Progress in such a section and mark it *submitted, awaiting editor decision*.

This is both honest and, IMO, an advantage. I think that having a valid Work in Progress section is always a plus in such things.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply! I already had it in my CV under Papers/Preprints section where I listed the paper's status as recommended for publication (revision under review) The reason I wanted to  list it outside of my CV whenever possible is because this is my first serious academic paper and I really wanted it pointed out somewhere in addition to my CV.

Comment: If it is in the CV then it will be seen.

Comment: I see I see. Thanks! Sorry for the trouble but one last question: what about schools for which I've already done this? Do you think that maybe I should email them and tell them what's actually going on? Or do you think I should just let it be? Given that my CV has already indicated this.

Comment: Decide whether what you wrote is completely honest or might appear to be padding. It could go either way depending on what you wrote. It might be clear to readers or not.